# cakephp move to server blank page

Tags: cakephp, apache2

It gives me "you don't have permission to access /cakephp/app/webroot on this server"

I changed permissions for both document root and /webroot to read/execute all

I changed the apache2 sites-available/default file to

```
<Directory /var/www/> ...
AllowOverride All 
...
```

Help

Comment: I did a fresh install of cakephp, and that seemed to solve the problem.  I must have messed up some permissions somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a fresh install of cakephp and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

sites-available is different from sites-enabled, might want to look there.

Comment: sites-enabled has a single file default-000 that is a link pointing to the file in sites-available.  That's the one I edited.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your firewall logs. It might be blocking something. Is this a Linux server? Also, please provide your entire `<Directory ...>` verbiage.